# show content of file and sort the content output

Tags: linux, cat

very simple question (i'm guessing.)

i use `cat <filename.txt> | grep "word:" | awk '{print $2}'`

and get the desired info like so

```
[user@server ~]# cat <filename.txt> | grep "word:" | awk '{print $2}'
403
404
423
406
401
```

how do i sort the number like so instead of the above

```
403,404,423,406,401
```

Comment: just add `| sort` ?…

Comment: Your example output doesn't appear to be sorted. Are you asking how to get the output on a single line, rather than on multiple lines?

Comment: correct, instead of list of results one line with comma between each number

Answer (score 0):

All this can be done via one command with `awk`:

```
awk '/word:/ {printf "%s%s", $2,","} END {print}' <input file>|sed 's/,$//'
```

The `sed` is used to remove last comma from the print.

to simplify the print you can use something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS=","} /word:/ {print $2}' <input file>|sed 's/,$//'
```

Comment: wow
> awk '/word:/ {printf "%s%s", $2,","} END {print}' <input file>|sed 's/,$//'
worked almost perfect but cuaght irrelevant string from the file not included in the word:

Comment: @NickVeronski, please provide part of input file in your question, otherwise the answers will be game of guess.

Comment: **awk '/word:/ {printf "%s%s", $2,","} END {print}' /filename.log |sed 's/,$//'**
resulted in output
5030,4589,5134,4831,4798,4364,4838,5049,4847,4801,4059,42923,4880,4809,4862,4963,4785,4921,4798,4928,4873,5024,4893,4831,4891,4981,4653,4832,4953,4776,4475,**Tue 06 Feb 2024 01:47:02 PM IST**

Comment: @NickVeronski, **add in question part of input file**

Comment: this is part of the file content
this section below is statistics and repeated many times
i'm filtering the number of (downtime:)

but the command output gave me also the end of file



Tue 06 Feb 2024 01:41:12 PM IST

Tue 06 Feb 2024 01:46:24 PM IST


**downtime: 4475 ms**

Tue 06 Feb 2024 01:47:02 PM IST

i can't seem to sort it like i see in the console

Comment: @NickVeronski, edit the question and add the information there (from the source file, not result). https://serverfault.com/posts/1153010/edit

Comment: `'BEGIN { ORS=","} /word:/ { print $2; }'` seems like a neater way of doing this to me. It would be possible to omit the sed too - but then the awk code starts getting clunky.

Comment: @symcbean, you are right, will "steal" your code :)

Comment: @symcbean, for me it print the last comma, so can't omit `sed` :(

Comment: Yes - code presented here was not intended to do that - as per comment above, its possible within the awk code but I stopped trying to work out how when it was getting too wordy.

Comment: @symcbean, nevertheless the idea with `ORS` is very good :)